# JavaScript DOM manipulation: can't replace innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to replace the content within the `<p>` tags with class `Binary_out` and `Text_out`, but I can't get the script to work, what am I doing wrong? I have pasted my HTML below. My JavaScript is at the bottom of the HTML, surrounded by `<script>` tags, as usual.

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Greatpage_Data/Style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text to binary converter</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <form action="">
    Text input:<br>
    <input type="text" name="text" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </td>

    <td>
    <p class="Binary_out"></p>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <form action="">
    Binary input:<br>
    <input type="text" name="binary">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </td>

    <td>
    <p class="Text_out"></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>var BinaryOut = document.getElementByClassName("Binary_Out");
var TextOut = document.getElementByClassName("Text_Out");

TextOut.innerHTML = "Testing";
BinaryOut.innerHTML = "Testing 2";
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName` and this returns an array of elements with that classname

Comment: @Praveen Actually it returns a `NodeList`, which behaves slightly different.

Comment: Please [use the **search**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+getElementByClassName) before you ask a new question. Searching for typos is actually pretty effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your script.  Firstly, it's `getElementsByClassName` (plural), and secondly that returns an array so you'd need to specify the first element.  Finally, `getElementsByClassName` is case sensitive and you got the case wrong when trying to select the elements...

```
<script>
    var BinaryOut = document.getElementsByClassName("Binary_out")[0];
    var TextOut = document.getElementsByClassName("Text_out")[0];

    TextOut.innerHTML = "Testing";
    BinaryOut.innerHTML = "Testing 2";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using your browser's console for this type of debugging. If you're on Chrome and using Mac, hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. You would've seen this error: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function`.

To select the element, you need to do `document.getElementsByClassName('whatever-class')[0]` to get the first element, `[1]` to get the second element, etc.

This method returns an array-like object of DOM nodes, called a `NodeList`.

Comment: For me (windows) on Chrome, it's `ctrl+shift+c`

Comment: Has _nobody_ here heard of `F12`?

Comment: @bbill, Yeah my bad, forgot to put "if you're on Mac". Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: @JoshBeam and Chrome, and Firebug in Firefox

Comment: So what you need to do to set it is `document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].innerHTML = 'base';`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you want `getElementsByClassName`, and it is also case sensitive.

In your HTML, the class names are `Binary_out` and `Text_out` as opposed to `Binary_Out` and `Text_Out`.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the documentation for the function you're using, `getElement(s)ByClassName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

It returns a NodeList; it's possible to have many elements with the same class. That page also has an example of how to filter for the elements you want, or you can use `getElementById`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Please explain the downvotes. I didn't catch every error but I'm not wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would assume part of it may be because it doesn't quite return an array as you stated (it returns a NodeList, which isn't an array object, explicitly.) I personally would not have seen that as a reason to downvote, though.

Comment: Sure, saw the comments above and edited the answer. I'm pretty sure that wasn't the reason it was downvoted because the comments came much later. Whatever, I'm done with this question.